# Configuring avahi in raspbian

Tags: jessie-lite, raspbian-lite

I am trying to configure avahi-daemon on my raspberry pi to broadcast the service I just programmed, which needs to be discoverable automatically. It sorta works, but not quite, and I cannot figure out why not.

If I use:

```
avahi-publish -s myservice _mqtt._tcp 1883
```

it works just fine, but that doesn't configure it to start automatically. For that I need to add it to a config, so I did just that. I added myservice.service in /etc/avahi/services with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?><!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
 <name replace-wildcards="yes">myservice</name>
  <service>
   <type>_mqtt._tcp</type>
   <port>1883</port>
   </service>
</service-group>
```

This should work on boot (according to all the documentation I've seen), but doesn't. It also doesn't work if I run

```
sudo systemctl status avahi-daemon
```

It doesn't give an error. It just doesn't publish my service (despite the log saying it read my config file).

However, and this is where it gets weird: if I copy the default ssh.service over from the avahi documentation and then RERUN the systemctl command above, it recognizes a "change" in the service files, reloads and then BOTH ssh and myservice are published correctly. Moreover, if I then remove ssh.service and run systemctl again, it recognizes that ssh.service is gone, and removes that service, but leaves myservice completely functional. However, if I reboot the device, it stops working again.

Moreover, if I leave ssh.service and reboot it also doesn't work...

I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Glad to see you posted it here =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more mucking about and some further googling, I found this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/avahi/+bug/624043

Apparently it's a bug (listed for Ubuntu, but I got it too, so presumably a bug with avahi in general). The workaround in answer #17 worked for me.

I added

```
systemctl reload avahi-daemon
```

to my rc.local script, and that fixed it. I still have no idea what is causing the bizar behaviour, but this seems to force a reload of the config, and that works.